# Disable the Test-flight build updating window

Tags: ios6, testflight

I have added test-flight SDK into my project.when I upload build on test-flight and download that build using test-flight shorten link,i get the test-flight updating window even if my build is new one.I want disable that test-flight screen which is appearing inside my application.if any one known about this please help me.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem that I reported to Tesflight. It is apparently a known bug.

A workaround is to completely turn off in app update with the following line:

```
[TestFlight setOptions:@{@"disableInAppUpdates":@YES}];
```

It only works with the 1.1 version of the SDK thus far.

Answer (score 2):

I found that if I didn't increase my ios application target version number, I would always get the faulty update window.